# exoplayer and react native seek bridge issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
<NativePlayer
                        style={[styles.player.video]}
                        playbackState={this.state.playbackState}
                        src={url}
                        streamTime={this.state.streamTime}
                    volume={this.state.volume}
```

I have some code here that takes the src for a video and the starting streamTime.

here is the react bridge code:

```
    @ReactProp (name = PROP_SEEK)
    public void setSeek(final ReactExoPlayerView playerView, final float seek) {
        playerView.seekTo(Math.round(seek * 1000f));
    }


    @ReactProp(name = PROP_SRC)
    public void setSrc(final ReactExoPlayerView videoView, @Nullable String src) {
        videoView.setSrc(src);
    }
```

My issue is that when I pass the src url and the streamtime to a react native bridge via the ReactProp, it treats the react props seperately, ie: it will first try to call videoView.seekTo() but there is no src set yet so nothing happens. Then it will call setSrc() which will set the correct video, but then there is no seek value since this was called BEFORE the setSrc  reactProp method was called.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

so I would set a variable called seekPosition, then when the source is loaded it will check this variable and seek to the right place.  If source is called before PROP_SEEK is called it will have the src already.